# Maximum sum of squared differences

Tags: algorithm

I have this problem, 2 sets A={a1,a2,...,an} and B={b1, b2,...,bn}, I need to permute their elements, so that their differences squared sum (a1 - b1)^2 + (a2 - b2)^2 +... + (an - bn)^2 is maximum.

Seems simple, greedy approach, I would sort A and inversely sort B, is there any more to it? Some trick I'm missing?

Comment: it can be proved that it holds using the rearrangement inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, sounds pretty straight forward, here is some pseudocode to help you out:

```
l1: list ordered least to greatest
l2: list ordered greatest to least

sum = 0
for i in 0...l1.length:
    sum += (l1[i] - l2[i])^2
return sum
```

Runtime should be bounded by the sorting algorithm you use, so probably `O(nlogn)`